RuntimeError: Internal Triton PTX codegen error while trying to train model Llama-3
I am trying to train Llama-3 model in Google collab with some data but I keep getting the following error:

RuntimeError: Internal Triton PTX codegen error:  ptxas /tmp/compile-ptx-src-9819d0, line 99; error   : Feature '.bf16' requires .target sm_80 or higher ptxas /tmp/compile-ptx-src-9819d0, line 99; error   : Feature 'cvt with .f32.bf16' requires .target sm_80 or higher ptxas /tmp/compile-ptx-src-9819d0, line 110; error   : Feature '.bf16' requires .target sm_80 or higher ptxas /tmp/compile-ptx-src-9819d0, line 110; error   : Feature 'cvt with .f32.bf16' requires .target sm_80 or higher ptxas /tmp/compile-ptx-src-9819d0, line 121; error   : Feature '.bf16' requires .target sm_80 or higher ptxas /tmp/compile-ptx-src-9819d0, line 121; error   : Feature 'cvt.bf16.f32' requires .target sm_80 or higher ptxas /tmp/compile-ptx-src-9819d0, line 130; error   : Feature '.bf16' requires .target sm_80 or higher ptxas /tmp/compile-ptx-src-9819d0, line 130; error   : Feature 'cvt.bf16.f32' requires .target sm_80 or higher ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors 

What could I do to solve it? I have read on the internet that it could be because the GPU is not powerful enough, as I am using the Google collab free version, but I have seen videos of people training the model that do not need to pay to be able to do it. My code is:
# Loading the model and the tokinizer for the model
model, tokenizer = FastLanguageModel.from_pretrained(
    model_name = 'unsloth/llama-3-8b-Instruct-bnb-4bit',
    max_seq_length = 2048,
    dtype = torch.float16,
    load_in_4bit = True,
)

# Setup for QLoRA/LoRA peft of the base model
model = FastLanguageModel.get_peft_model(
    model,
    r = 16,
    target_modules = ["q_proj", "k_proj", "v_proj", "o_proj",
                      "gate_proj", "up_proj", "down_proj"],
    lora_alpha = 16,
    lora_dropout = 0,
    bias = 'none',
    use_gradient_checkpointing = True,
    random_state = 888,
    use_rslora = False,
    use_dora = False,
    loftq_config = None,
)

data = pd.read_csv('training_test_data.csv')

n_splits = 2
kf = KFold(n_splits = n_splits, shuffle = False)

real_phrases = []
generated_phrases = []
lemmas = []

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(data):
  print('a')
  training_data, test_data = data['text'][train_index], data['text'][test_index]

  training_data = Dataset.from_pandas(training_data.to_frame().reset_index())
  test_data = Dataset.from_pandas(test_data.to_frame().reset_index())

  trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model = model,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,
    train_dataset = training_data,
    dataset_text_field = 'text',
    max_seq_length = 2048,
    dataset_num_proc = 2,
    packing = False,
    args = TrainingArguments(
        per_device_train_batch_size = 2,
        gradient_accumulation_steps = 4,
        warmup_steps = 5,
        max_steps = 5,
        learning_rate = 2e-4,
        fp16 = not torch.cuda.is_bf16_supported(),
        bf16 = torch.cuda.is_bf16_supported(),
        logging_steps = 1,
        optim = 'adamw_8bit',
        weight_decay = 0.01,
        lr_scheduler_type = 'linear',
        seed = 888,
        output_dir = 'outputs'
    )
  )

  trainer.train()

  for p in test_data:
    text = p['text'].split('Phrase: ')
    prompt = text[0]
    ph = text[1]
    real_phrases.append(ph)
    lemmas.append(prompt.split('Lemmas: ')[1].strip('\n'))

    inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors = 'pt')
    generate_ids = model.generate(inputs.input_ids, max_length = 50)
    output = tokenizer.batch_decode(generate_ids, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False)[0]

    try:
      generated_phrases.append(output.split('Phrase: ')[1])
    except:
      generated_phrases.append('')

Any help woul be good help : ) Thank you !!
I have tried uninstalling and installing again xformers, as I saw in other page, but it did not work. Also have tried different parameters but I keep getting the mistake.
